# How to use an ExecutorCompletionService

Tags: java

I would like to use the constructor on the `ExecutorCompletionService` which takes a pre-defined `BlockingQueue`.

Can anyone provide a code snippet to show how this is done.  It seems only to take a a `BlockingQueue` with `Future`s.  How does this match with the fact that submit must be done with `Callable`s.

I'm getting a little confused here - please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Callables` supplied to [`submit()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html#submit%28java.util.concurrent.Callable%29) will be wrapped up internally as [`FutureTask`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html)s, and it's those (or a wrapper around one) that will eventually be inserted into the provided queue. That's all an implementation detail, though. (And, note, that this use case of inserting the outcome into the queue is the main reason why there's a protected [`done()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html#done()) method in `FutureTask`.) The contract says that result-yielding functions go in, and eventually results come out. The `Future`s drawn from the queue represent the eventual outcomes of the functions you submitted earlier.

Answer (score 1):

The [javadoc for ExecutorCompletionService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html) has a large code sample in it, and the documented constructor takes a `BlockingQueue`.

Comment: Yes I've looked at that it doesn't help me because the large block of code doesn't use the constructor I need - have you ever tried this yourself?

Comment: As I said, the javadoc also shows a constructor that takes a  `BlockingQueue`